# Can contracts trade on etherdelta?

Tags: solidity, transactions, contract-design, signature, etherdelta

I was told that contracts can not trade on etherdelta because they can not sign transactions, could someone clarify?

Comment: It is a [contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x8d12a197cb00d4747a1fe03395095ce2a5cc6819#code) you should be able to interact with it like any other contract.